# Why is member function return type instantiated much later than the expression types it depends on?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Pardon the confusing title.

I have this code, which is accepted by GCC, Clang, and MSVC:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Reader
{
    friend auto adl(Reader<T>);
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Writer
{
    friend auto adl(Reader<T>) {return U{};}
};

struct A
{
    struct Tag {};
    auto helper() -> decltype(void(Writer<Tag,decltype(this)>{})) {}
    using Self = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(adl(Reader<Tag>{}))>;
};
```

It uses stateful metaprogramming to write a type, and then read it back.

Notice the weird use of `Writer`. I thought I could simplify it to:

```
auto helper() -> Writer<Tag,decltype(this)> {return {};}
```

But then it stops working (on all three compilers), due to `Writer` being instantiated after the read happens. <kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:22,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:22,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:22,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:22,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+Reader%0A%7B%0A++++friend+auto+adl(Reader%3CT%3E)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+U%3E%0Astruct+Writer%0A%7B%0A++++friend+auto+adl(Reader%3CT%3E)+%7Breturn+U%7B%7D%3B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++struct+Tag+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++auto+helper()+-%3E+Writer%3CTag,decltype(this)%3E+%7Breturn+%7B%7D%3B%7D%0A++++using+Self+%3D+std::remove_pointer_t%3Cdecltype(adl(Reader%3CTag%3E%7B%7D))%3E%3B%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.26370757180157,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-Wdeprecated%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.20744878577278,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:46.73629242819843,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

But if I then move `using Self = ...` to a `static` function body below `helper`, it starts working again. Meaning `Writer` is now instantiated along with the body of `helper`, not with its declaration.

After experimenting with different return types, it seems that `Writer` is instantiated early whenever it's used as a type of an *expression*. Here's another example: `auto helper() -> std::enable_if_t<(Writer<Tag,decltype(this)>{}, true), void> {}`

What causes this difference? Since the three compilers agree on this, it's not a fluke of stateful templates, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `auto helper() -> Writer<Tag,decltype(this)>;` doesn't cause instantiation of `Writer<Tag,decltype(this)>` because the return type is not required to be complete.

The definition of `helper()` and with it the implicit instantiation of `Writer<Tag,decltype(this)>` are then in a complete-class context, which it seems the compilers assume means that the member function definition is located after the class definition and that the point-of-instantiation of `Writer<Tag,decltype(this)>` is then also after the class definition.

I don't know whether this is actually how it is supposed to work or which paragraph in the standard would specify this behavior, though.

Reading the tag only in the body of another (static) member function causes the read to also be located in a complete class context, i.e. after the class definition in the above interpretation, which is why it works again.